# Sql Distinct Count of resulting table with no conditionals

Tags: sql

I want to count the number of accounts from the resulting table generated from this code. This way, I know how many people liked blue at one time.

```
Select Distinct PEOPLE.FullName, PEOPLE.FavColor From PEOPLE
Where FavColor='Blue'
```

Lets say this is a history accounting of what people said their favorite color when they were asked so there may be multiple records of the same full name if asked again at a much later time; hence the distinct.

The code I used may not be reusable in your answer so feel free to use what you think can work. I am sure I found a possible solution to my problem using declare and if statements but I lost that page... so I am left with no solution. However, I think there is a way to do it without using conditionals which is what I am asking and rather have. Thanks.

Edit: My question is: From the code above, is there a way to count the number of accounts in the resulting table?

Comment: I don't get it - what's the question?  What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry about that, I hope that edit made the question clearer. I am checking everyone's responses now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking correctly (*how many people liked blue at one time?*), try this:

```
select count(*)
from PEOPLE
where FavColor = 'Blue'
group by FullName
```

If your question is in fact, *how can I count the results of any select query?*, you can do this:

Suppose your original query is:

```
select MyColumn
from MyTable
where MyOtherColumn = 26
```

You can wrap it in another query to get the count

```
select count(*)
from (
    select MyColumn
    from MyTable
    where MyOtherColumn = 26
) a
```

Comment: This is well written. Originally, I thought I had to select every column I was going to use in the first place. I did not know I could state "MyOtherColumn" even if it wasn't in the beginning select.

Comment: I liked the last answer and detailed description. I had to add distinct to mycolumn of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you want.

Select Count(*) as 'NumberOfPeople'
From 
(
Select Distinct PEOPLE.FullName, PEOPLE.FavColor From PEOPLE
Where FavColor='Blue'
)a

Comment: This looks very interesting, but it didn't work for me. What is the a? It looks like a variable for the sub select or something (I am still a beginner at sql)

Comment: Sorry about that you don't need the a. in the select - i've edited my original answer

Comment: @AfterImage - the "a" is a table alias, which is required for subqueries in a FROM close in some versions of SQL. It is the name that may be used to reference the results of the subquery within the outer SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Count (Distinct PEOPLE.FullName)  
From PEOPLE  
Where FavColor='Blue'
```

Comment: This certainly was the simplest one. I would have chosen this but Orb described in detail and wrapping around a subquery was what I was aimming for. Even though I didn't notice it at first. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want to generate the count with no WHERE clause?

How about this?

```
SELECT
    count(*)
FROM
    people
    INNER JOIN (SELECT FavColor = 'Blue') col ON col.FavColor = people.FavColor
```

Edit: OK, I see what you want now.

You just need to wrap your query in `SELECT count(*) FROM ( <your-query-goes-here> )`.

Answer (score 0):

If the same person has multiple answers, that is, their favourite colour has changed over time  - resulting in several colours, some repeating, for the same person (aka "account") then to find the number of accounts where the favourite colour is / was blue (oracle):

select count(*) 
  from (select FULLNAME
          from PEOPLE
         where FAVCOLOR = 'BLUE'
       group by FULLNAME);

Comment: Your description was exactly what I was asking. As for the oracle, I am not sure. Did it account for distinct fullnames?